# Conditionally run app.ts from different src folders - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, migration

I have re-written an application copying code from `src` (old) to `src2` (new). Now I want to make a switch between those two apps in run time based on a swagger response. If the swagger returns v2 it should pick the entry point from `src2` folder, if it returns v1 start from old `src`. Since this is something new, I am looking for possible approaches to make the conditional switch.

- One is to have the condition in index.js and start the correct app.ts

[image]

Comment: both src and src_v2 have save design

Comment: @MahammadMomin wdym save design?

Comment: means same code